# write information into a file x times in a certain format

Tags: xml, list, file, python-3.x, loops

What my issue is is that I am taking a simple txt file, stripping the XML tags manually (without xml.etree). I've done all of  that, but when I go to write the info into the new file. I am having 2 issues.

1. I am unsure how to write it to be able to fit the information into the file as many times as desired in a specific format.

So right now I can only do the first person.
Whereas I want to do any number of people.

2. I don't know how to go about counting the number of  are in the file.

I figured doing some count method would work. Just am unsure how to implement it.

So what my code looks like now:

```
def peopleData(fileName):
    readFile = open(fileName, "r").read()
    newFile = input("")
    writeFile = open(newFile, "w")
    listA = []
    with open(fileName, "r") as file:
        for tags in file:
            strippedtags = str(tags.split(">")[1].split("<")[0])
            listA.append(strippedtags.strip())
    writeFile.write("{} {}, ".format(listA[2], listA[3])) #fname, lname
    writeFile.write("He is {} years old. ".format(listA[4])) #age
    writeFile.write("He went to {}.".format(listA[5])+"\n") #school
    writeFile.close
```

When I execute the function I get the information on the first person and it's exactly how I want it.

```
"Travis Anderson. He is 24 years old. He went to Nebraska."
```

But for the rest of the people I don't know how to make them be written in the same way the first person is. Like this.

```
"Travis Anderson. He is 24 years old. He went to Nebraska."
"James Kritten. He is 23 years old. He went to Texas State."
"Kaine Allen. He is 27 years old. He went to Michigan State."
```

I assume I need some sort of loop, but I don't know where to start with it.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a constant number of tags per person (let's say 5) I would suggest the following:

```
def peopleData(fileName):
    newFile = input("")
    listA = []
    counter = 0
    with open(fileName, "r") as file, open(newFile, "w") as writeFile:
        for tags in file:
            strippedtags = str(tags.split(">")[1].split("<")[0]).strip()
            listA.append(strippedtags)
            if counter % 5 == 0:
                writeFile.write("{} {}, ".format(listA[2], listA[3])) #fname, lname
                writeFile.write("He is {} years old. ".format(listA[4])) #age
                writeFile.write("He went to {}.".format(listA[5])+"\n") #school
                listA = []
            counter+=1
```